# Find document that has string in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

At this moment I have a Mongoose/MongoDB schema which has the following field:

```
cuisines: [{
  type: String
}],
```

I'm trying to find documents that contain one of the results inside the array.. so the array could look like:

```
[BBQ, Chicken, Asian]
```

My query currently returns no result:

```
caterers = await Caterer.find({ cuisines: { $in: [req.body.cuisine] } })
```

Is there an alternative to $in that finds all documents in which the string passed in the req.body is present?

The string I'm passing in `req.body.cuisine` is `BBQ`, however, unless I specify all results stored in the Array, I get no results(?)

Comment: Is `req.body.cuisine` a `string`?

Comment: If `req.body.cuisine` is a string then a simple query `await Caterer.find({ cuisines: req.body.cuisine })` should suffice, no need for `$in`

Comment: It seems like `cuisines:` is an array of String, is that so ?

Comment: @mansoor Correct, if I were to output cuisines it's formatted like ```"cuisines" : [ "BBQ, Mexican" ]```

Comment: @AsafAviv Yes, req.body.cuisine is a string. Previously no results were returned unless I specified both results that are stored in the array i.e. BBQ, Chicken, Asian as req.body.cuisine